# Need add a top header title in Wordpress Home Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I need to add a top header text on the home page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beGJr.png). I have enabled the top header option on customization [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jissg.png). But I don't have any option to add the text there. How to add that. The text I want to add is " All island delivery available"

Comment: Would you upload the image to https://prnt.sc.

Comment: If there's no theme/customizer option available then you'll have to create a [Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and override the header file.

Comment: How to override that file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to your theme folder & edit functions.php then paste the below code. hopefully, work it. You can customize your markup & style what you need.
For better understanding I include a [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/UaG_WiWPA0QT).

```
function header_top(){
    $data =  <<<HELLO
        <div class="header-top-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>All island delivery available</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    HELLO;

    echo $data;
}
add_action('wp_body_open','header_top');
```

Goto theme customizer & find Additional CSS & paste below style.

```
.header-top-section{
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.text-center{
    text-align: center !important;
}

.header-top-section p{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Finally you can see your expected output. https://prnt.sc/hzIAhUAAQ3xy